# Run tests multiple times with different beforeEach

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

So I have these 2 cases in my tests. First one works fine, in the second one I try to extract the beforeEach declaration outside and it fails but I don't understand why. This is a simple case, basically I try to define an array and make a loop on that in order to run the tests multimple time with different beforeEach params declaration.

CASE 1

```
var params;

describe('When initializing', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        params = {
            name: 'test 1'
        };         
    });

    it('should ..', function () {                              
        params.name = 'test 2';
        expect(...); => success
    });

    it('should ..', function () {                              
        expect(...); => success because it expects params.name to be 'test 1' and it is 'test 1'
    });
});
```

CASE 2

```
var params;

var test = {
    name: 'test 1'
};

describe('When initializing', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        params = test;            
    });

    it('should ..', function () {                              
        params.name = 'test 2';
        expect(...); => success
    });

    it('should ..', function () {                              
        expect(...); => fails because it expects params.name to be 'test 1' and it is 'test 2'
    });
});
```

In the second test if I `console.log(test.name)` inside the describe I will get `test 2`, somehow it got overriden even though the previous `it` did just `params.name = 'test 2';` and not `test.name = 'test 2';`

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that in case 1 you're creating a new object every time beforeEach is called, while in case 2 you're not.

Combined with that is the fact that your first test mutates the object. If all the tests are referring to the same object (ie, case 2) then that mutation will affect any code that runs after the first test. If instead the object is overwritten before each test (case 1), then the mutation won't affect other tests.

There are a few options for how to address this. One is to just to keep case 1; by resetting to a known state each time, you can have a clean state for all the tests to work off of. Another option is to not mutate the object. Perhaps the tests could copy the object and then modify that copy.

Comment: Hi. It doesn't make any sense. The first test is exactly the second test with the only thing that in the second one, the object is extracted outside. The test variable is not mutated at any point and that one is being used inside beforeEach. What do you mean by my second  test is not creating a new object, because it's the same test, it has the beforeEach also, so it should create the object right ? My question is why the second test is not working because I need to use it like that.

Comment: `The first test is exactly the second test with the only thing that in the second one, the object is extracted outside.` The result of this is that you're creating the params/test object only once (before the describe), then making repeated references to that same object. In case 1 you create a completely new object before each test. `The test variable is not mutated at any point` the mutation happens on this line: `params.name = 'test 2';`

Comment: Just in case it's not clear, `params = test; ` does **not** copy the object or create a new object. It just makes another reference to the same existing object.

Comment: That is not the test variable, that is the params variable which is also mutated in the first test also.

Comment: They're the same thing. You just have two references to the same object.

Comment: So should I use params = angular.copy(test) to fix this?

Comment: Yes, copying the object is one way to fix it. If you're using angularJS, you can do angular.copy. Other alternatives include `params = Object.assign({}, test)` or `params = {...test}` if you can use object spread syntax (a fairly recent addition to the language)